# How to restart network adapter after sleep state with powershell in win8?

Tags: powershell, wifi, scheduled-tasks

I need to automatically restart my wi-fi when my netbook starts from sleep state. I have created the task with following properties in task scheduler:

(General tab)

- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Run with highest privilages
- Configure for Windows 8

(Triggers)

- On an event
- Log: System
- Source: Kernel-Power
- Event ID: 42
- Enabled

(Conditions)

- I have unchecked every option in this tab

(Settings)

- Allow task to be run on demand
- Stop the task if it runs longer then: 15 seconds
- If the running task does not end when requested, force it to stop

(Actions)

- Start a program: path to my following powershell script:

> ```
> $wifi = Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter|where {$_.name -like "*wireless*"}
> $wifi.disable()
> $wifi.enable()
> ```

When i run the script manually everything works just fine, but when i try to use above task nothing happens and the 'last run result' equals 0x41301, what i believe means 'task is still runing'. It should not, as when started manually it takes about 1 second to perform.

Cheers,
Kasper

Comment: Have you tried Restart-Netadapter  ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I can restart netadapter with my script. The problem is that Task Scheduler can't finish it for some reasons.

Comment: @kasper in windows 8, there is a specific command called Restart-NetAdapter. You don't need wmi. Perhaps it's more reliable than direct wmi: `get-netadapter "wi-fi" | restart-netadapter`

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating.  x0n did for me though.  I had to run, but wanted to give you a possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok guys, I have found the solution to my problem.

It was due to misleading field title in 'Actions' tab - in Settings section 'Program/Script'. My intuition told me that it is ok to put path to the PowerShell script directly, but...

NO!

I had to put path to PowerShell instead (C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe by default) and give path to my restart-netadapter script as an argument ('Add argument (optional)' field). Now it works like a charm.

That wasn't very intuitive.

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 2):

As @mike said in his comment, in Windows 8, there is a specific command called `Restart-NetAdapter`. You don't need WMI. Perhaps it's more reliable than direct WMI. Use:

`get-netadapter "wi-fi" | restart-netadapter`

PowerShell v3's autoloading will take care of loading the correct module. Also, pay attention to which user you are using for the task. Certain system accounts may lack the rights to do this work.

Comment: Yeah, I get `restart-netadapter : Access is denied.` message and adapter is not restarted. Still, I am not sure if the problems lies in my script, which works when I trigger it manually. I just can't get it work with Task Scheduler.

Comment: Starting PowerShell with administrator privilages solve the denial problem, but I still get 0x41301 status on 'Last Run Result' in Task Scheduler.